# Style clash when try to create different border radius responsive properties in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying the layout attached. Basically changing border props on smaller screens but because the classes are clashing, it's not working. Anyone have any ideas on how I'd achieve this? Code below. Thanks in advance.

```
   <div class="font-sm md:gap-x-0.75 mt-1 grid grid-cols-1 gap-[0.625rem] md:grid-cols-3">
        <div>
          <span class="font-bold">Need-Based Scholarships and Grants </span>
          <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
          <div class="mt-1 bg-[#f4f4f4] border rounded-bl-xl rounded-tl-xl rounded-tr-none border-gray-detailBorder md:rounded-bl-none rounded-tr-xl rounded-tl-xl border-gray-detailBorder py-1.25 px-0.75 items-center col-span-1 md:col-span-2 text-center md:w-full">
              <p>
                <span class="text-blue block text-[1.75rem] font-semibold leading-9" id="costs-students-awarded-grants-percent"> PH% </span>
                <span class="mt-0.5 block text-sm font-medium leading-[1.125rem]"> Average Awarded </span>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="mt-1 md:mt-0 bg-[#f4f4f4] border rounded-none border-gray-detailBorder md:rounded-b-xl py-1.25 px-0.75 flex-col items-center md:border-t-0 col-span-1 md:col-span-2 text-center md:w-full">
              <p>
                <span class="text-blue block text-[1.75rem] font-semibold leading-9" id="costs-students-awarded-grants-percent"> PH% </span>
                <span class="mt-0.5 block text-sm font-medium leading-[1.125rem]"> Undergraduates Awarded </span>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/1BaETeFqGY

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the class names as below:
You can achieve your layout with the below code.

```
 <div class="font-sm md:gap-x-0.75 mt-1 grid grid-cols-1 gap-[0.625rem] md:grid-cols-3">
  <div>
    <span class="font-bold">Need-Based Scholarships and Grants </span>
    <div class="grid grid-cols-2">
      <div class="border-gray-detailBorder border-gray-detailBorder py-1.25 px-0.75 col-span-1 mt-1 items-center rounded-l-xl border bg-[#f4f4f4] text-center md:col-span-2 md:w-full md:rounded-l-none md:rounded-t-xl">
        <p>
          <span class="text-blue block text-[1.75rem] font-semibold leading-9" id="costs-students-awarded-grants-percent"> PH% </span>
          <span class="mt-0.5 block text-sm font-medium leading-[1.125rem]"> Average Awarded </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="border-gray-detailBorder py-1.25 px-0.75 col-span-1 mt-1 flex-col items-center rounded-r-xl border bg-[#f4f4f4] text-center md:col-span-2 md:mt-0 md:w-full md:rounded-r-none md:rounded-bl-xl md:rounded-br-xl">
        <p>
          <span class="text-blue block text-[1.75rem] font-semibold leading-9" id="costs-students-awarded-grants-percent"> PH% </span>
          <span class="mt-0.5 block text-sm font-medium leading-[1.125rem]"> Undergraduates Awarded </span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/GYO1vCfnsE?size=1128x720